# Proper way of restarting SQL Node with Availability Groups and Replication

Tags: sql-server, restart, alwayson

I have active/active cluster with availability groups in async mode on both parts of that cluster, so each node is being used as a Primary and a Secondary replica at the same time. Also we have a Transactional Replication from Node1 to Node2. 
Windows admin finished some maintenance on Node1 and at some point we need just to reboot Node1. Outage will be short and is expected. What is the proper way of doing the reboot of Node1 considering we have AlwaysOn and Replication?
Thank you

Comment: why use Availability Groups AND Replication?

Answer (score -4):

You have to stop replication jobs. failover to node 2 . start node 1 
fail over back to node 1 .Start Replication jobs